# Partial fraction - calculate $k_1$ $k_2$ and $k_3$

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I have the following problem:

> Calculate $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ in this equation:
>
> $$\frac{s+13}{(s+2)(s+11)(s+8)}=\frac{k_1}{s+2}+\frac{k_2}{s+11}+\frac{k_3}{s+8}$$

I've searched on the internet and read in the book my instructor but it is very poorly explained and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: There are two classic approaches.  One is to clear the fractions, which gives a cubic in $s$ on both sides.  Identify like powers and you get three equations in three unknowns.  The other is to multiply by one denominator at a time, say $s+2$, then take the limit as $s \to -2$.  The other terms on the right go to zero and you get $k_1$ directly.  Do the same with the other two factors in the denominator.

Comment: Putting everything in the RHS into one fraction results in the equality:
$$s+13=k_1(s+11)(s+8)+k_2(s+2)(s+8)+k_3(s+2)(s+11)$$
Now, compare the coefficients of $1$, $s$, $s^2$ on both sides of the equation. This gives you a set of simultaneous equations. For instance, if you compare the coefficients of $s^2$ on both sides, you will get the equation (can you see how I got there?):
$$0=k_1+k_2+k_3$$

Comment: It  might have been better if you posted the stuff that was poorly explained and asked for help understanding.

Comment: Why do you think so? At the moment I have 4 different (and good) answers with different methods, explaining me how to sovle a problem like this. I couldn't ask for more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to find the unknowns by making true the identity you wrote above. For this you have to take the term on the right side and develop it:

$$\frac{k_1}{s+2} + \frac{k_2}{s+11} + \frac{k_3}{s+8} = \frac{k_1(s+11)(s+8) + k_2(s+2)(s+8) + k_3(s+2)(s+11)}{(s+2(s+11)(s+8)}$$

Now you have to develop and arrange the numerator by collecting the terms in $s^2$, $s$ and the constant terms, as functions of $k_i$:

The numerator becomes:

$$k_1(s^2 + 19s + 88) + k_2(s^2 + 10s + 16) + k_3(s^2 + 13s + 22)$$

That is

$$s^2(k_1 + k_2 + k_3) + s(19k_1 + 10k_2 + 13k_3) + 88k_1 + 16k_2 + 22k_3$$

Now it's about to check TERM BY TERM with your initial function: you see there are NO terms in $s^2$ hence it must be

$$k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 0$$

You see the term in $s$ must have coefficient $1$ so you need

$$19k_1 + 10k_2 + 13k_3 = 1$$

And eventually the constant is $13$ so you need

$$88k_1 + 16k_2 + 22k_3 = 13$$

Note that this gives you a system of three equations in three unknown. Can you go on from here? This will give you the $k_i$ terms.

Comment: I get answer of: $k_1 = \frac{11}{54}$ , $k_2 = \frac{2}{27}$ , $k_3 = \frac{-5}{18}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Carl It's correct!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for this clear explanation.

Comment: @Carl My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{k_1}{s+2}+\frac{k_2}{s+11}+\frac{k_3}{s+8} =\frac{k_1(s+11)(s+8)+k_2(s+2)(s+8)+k_3(s+2)(s+11)}{(s+2)(s+11)(s+8)}$

so multiply out the numerator on the right hand side and find the co-coefficients of $s^2$, $s^1$ and $s^0$.  Compare these with the coefficients in $s+13 = 0s^2+1s^1+13s^0$

That gives you three simultaneous equations in three unknowns, which you can solve.

For example for the coefficient of $s^2$ you get $k_1s^2+k_2s^2+k_3s^2$ so $k_1+k_2+k_3=0$.  I will leave the others to you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is to write:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{s+13}{(s+2)(s+11)(s+8)}
    &=\frac{k_1}{s+2}+\frac{k_2}{s+11}+\frac{k_3}{s+8} 
\end{align*}$

Multiply e.g. by $s + 8$ and compute the limit as $s \to - 8$:

$\begin{align*}
   \lim_{s \to -8}
     \frac{s+13}{(s+2)(s+11)}
    &= \lim_{s \to -8} \frac{k_1 (s + 8)}{s+2}
         + \lim_{s \to -8} \frac{k_2 (s + 8)}{s+11}
         + \lim_{s \to -8} k_3 \\
   \frac{-8 + 13}{(-8 + 2) (-  8 + 11)}
     &= k_3 \\
   k_3
     &= - \frac{5}{18}
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
  \frac{s+13}{(s+2)(s+11)(s+8)}
    =\frac{k_1}{s+2}+\frac{k_2}{s+11}+\frac{k_3}{s+8} 
$$

Another trick is to multiply through by $(s+2)(s+11)(s+8)$

$$
  s+13 = k_1(s+11)(s+8)+k_2(s+2)(s+8)+k_3(s+2)(s+11)
$$

Note, for example, that (s+8) is a factor of two out of three of the terms on the right.
So, if we let $s=-8$ and simplify, we get

\begin{align}
   5 &= -18 k_3 \\
   k_3 &= -\dfrac{5}{18}
\end{align}

The other two coefficients can be found in the same way.